# Rails 3 / ActiveAdmin controller_action won't return a plain JSON array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activeadmin

Contrived example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Something do
  # stuff

  controller_action :sad_trombone, :method => :get do
    render :json => ["wah", "wah", "wahhh"]
  end
end
```

I hit `/admin/somethings/sad_trombone`. The JSON response I get looks like this:

```
{ somethings: ["wah", "wah", "wahhh"] }
```

While I appreciate the convenient, automagical `somethings` namespace, I just need my `sad_trombone` controller to return a plain array, like so:

```
["wah", "wah", "wahhh"]
```

**How do I do that?**

If useful, I'm using:

```
activeadmin (0.6.0)
rails (3.2.13)
```

(This is just a simplified example for illustrative purposes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
render :json => ["wah", "wah", "wahhh"], :root => false
```

The `:root => false` option instructs Rails *not* to include a root JSON object -- in other words, just the plain data structure you want to return in the response.

---

In case it's helpful to posterity:

There are (at least) two other, but much more broad ways of accomplishing this:

```
ActiveRecord.Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

And:

```
my_model.to_json(:root => false)
```